# STM32 UART Transmit stops responding after some time

Tags: stm32, freertos

I am using a STM32L476RG NUCLEO Board with FreeRTOS and STM32 iCUBE LoRaWAN stack. I have a UART interface connected to Raspberry Pi, which periodically sends and receives data to-from STM32. I am using a circular buffer with DMA and IDLE Line detection as amount of data I receive is not fixed.

void HAL_UARTEx_RxEventCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart, uint16_t Size)
{

```
    if (huart->Instance == USART3)
    {

      //memcpy(MainBuf,RxBuf,Size);

            oldPos = newPos;  // Update the last position before copying new data

            /* If the data in large and it is about to exceed the buffer size, we have to route it to the start of the buffer
             * This is to maintain the circular buffer
             * The old data in the main buffer will be overlapped
             */
            if (oldPos+Size > MainBuf_SIZE)  // If the current position + new data size is greater than the main buffer
            {
                    uint16_t datatocopy = MainBuf_SIZE-oldPos;  // find out how much space is left in the main buffer
                    memcpy ((uint8_t *)MainBuf+oldPos, RxBuf, datatocopy);  // copy data in that remaining space

                    oldPos = 0;  // point to the start of the buffer
                    memcpy ((uint8_t *)MainBuf, (uint8_t *)RxBuf+datatocopy, (Size-datatocopy));  // copy the remaining data
                    newPos = ((Size)-datatocopy);  // update the position
            }

            /* if the current position + new data size is less than the main buffer
             * we will simply copy the data into the buffer and update the position
             */
            else
            {
                    memcpy (MainBuf+oldPos, RxBuf, Size);
                    newPos = Size+oldPos;
            }

    }

    print_mem_hex(RxBuf, Size);

    //HAL_UARTEx_ReceiveToIdle_DMA(&huart3, RxBuf, RxBuf_SIZE);
```

}

However,  UART Transmit stops after sometime.

I have followed the instructions  in

https://community.st.com/t5/stm32-mcus-products/stm32-uart-interrupt-stops-working-after-1-hour/td-p...

And have stopped and restarted my HAL_UART_Receive_IT().

However it seems not to work, Could you please give me some suggestions?

Comment: I looked at your code and it is terrible. No sync mechanisms  - you do not use RTOS (learn how to use tasks and IPS), multiple copy, nonsense use of goto and many other issues. I am  surprised that it works even for some time.

Comment: You need to detect the failure event and see what DMA/UART flags tell you (the source of the problem could be either). If there is no synchronization where there should be, it could be that (and it will be next to impossible to catch if that's the case, easier to fix it preventively and see if the problem goes away). Does the communication stop after around the same time? Or randomly, could be after a minute, could be after an hour?

Comment: @Ilya Problem is there is no failure event. It just stops UART Transmit. Receive works and after device reset everything seems to be working fine. Its not random, its approximately the same time.

Comment: @0___________Hi, thanks for the response. But Its not my code. I do use FreeRTOS. But I just wanted to link the overall idea of UART that I had used. I have edited the question since then to include my actual code snippet. Could you please give me your feedback now?

Comment: by "Failure event" I mean any abnormal behavior. Maybe you could put some supervisor (a function or another thread) that would keep an eye on DMA/UART flags so that it could detect when send doesn't happen anymore. Since UART receive seems to work, it could be DMA config that goes bad (I would imagine UART would stop to work entirely if it were on UART side, but it's just a guess). You could run your MCU while it's connected to CubeProgrammer, and when the MCU stops sending stuff, you could read out DMA and UART registers with the programmer, see what happened.